# Javadoc-like for C ? Complete documentation of libraries

Tags: c, documentation, javadoc, libraries

Is there a complete documentation of each libraries for the C language ? As we can find for Java.

Where do you search when you want to know all the functions in a library such as math.h and how to use these functions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I typically reference 
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ but there are other website that provide similar documentation.

On the above link, first find the library you are interested in (ex: stdio.h)
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/

If you scroll down you can see: Functions, Macros, and Types defined inside this header file.

Overall the C standard library is much smaller than what you get with Java. Here is a high level overview
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library

Answer (score 0):

I have used the [GNU C Library Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/) and this [website](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/). They pretty much cover all the library functions, both include examples.

There are also manpages in *NIX(Linux and Unix and other Unix-like) systems if you need information about specific functions without opening up your browser. For example, if you are looking for information about the function `getline()` you would type `man 3 getline` in the Terminal. The `man` command is the name of executable for the `manpages` application. The number 3 means you are looking for a library function and `getline` is the name of function of your interest.